# ms access custom multiple select list box in a form bound to sql server table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2010

I have a table in sql server 2008 called Program, some of the fields of program table are:

```
Program ID : nVarChar (Primary Key)
Program Name: nVarChar
Topic1 : bit
Topic2 : bit
Topic3 : bit
Topic4 : bit
```

The Program table looks something like this:

```
Program ID      Program Name      Topic1      Topic2      Topic3      Topic4

prog001         Program A            1          0           0           1
prog002         Program B            0          1           0           0
prog003         Program C            0          1           1           0
```

I am creating a form in MS Access 2010 for this Program table, which is a linked table in Access. I want to create a list box for the 4 fields (Topic1, Topic2, Topic3, Topic4) in the program table and allow multiple select. I want the list box to work as follows: Suppose I select the Topic1, Topic3 options from the list then the Topic1 and Topic3 fields in the program table should be populated with the bit value 1 and the unselected field options, that is, Topic2, Topic4 should be populated with 0.
Suppose I add a new record to the program table using the form then my Program table should look like this:
    The record added is the 4th row with Program ID: prog004

```
Program ID      Program Name      Topic1      Topic2      Topic3      Topic4

prog001         Program A            1          0           0           1
prog002         Program B            0          1           0           0
prog003         Program C            0          1           1           0
prog004         Program D            1          0           1           0
```

I actually want to get the effect of a combo box bound to a multivalue look-up field. I know we can't have multiple select option in combo box, so I thought of using a list box. But if there is any way I can get the list as a combo box with check boxes associated with each list item, which allows multiple select, that would be great.

Can someone give me some idea about how I can get this done.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link below has the answer to my question. I hope this will be helpful for someone who comes across the problem I had.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1f7127e-e6fe-4541-b8ac-e03b9c820cfa/access-2010-possible-to-create-check-listbox-elements-tied-to-sql-server-2008-backend?forum=accessdev#5389909a-378c-45d1-9960-9e0f17fb48d4